# Pandas Searching for Date formats and non-date formats in a Data Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is my scenario:

I need to search for . . . let's say the following 3 terms: 'apple', 'candy', and 'time'.

I also need to search for any values that come in a "MM/dd/yyyy".

I need to search an entire data frame column, column 'A', for all 4 of those things.

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df4

            A           Q           R           S
0       Apple       chair         red     english
1      orange        desk        blue      german
2        pear     monitor      yellow     spanish
3       Apple       chair      purple     english
4  10/01/2016  05/02/2004  05/05/2014  06/20/2018
5  02/20/2017  01/01/2017  07/07/2017  02/04/2004
```

The output I am expecting is this:

```
            A           Q           R           S
0       Apple       chair         red     english
3       Apple       chair      purple     english
4  10/01/2016  05/02/2004  05/05/2014  06/20/2018
5  02/20/2017  01/01/2017  07/07/2017  02/04/2004
```

Searching for actual words is no problem. Searching for words AND searching for date formats at the same time, is not something I know how to do.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How did you end up with this DF in the first place? It looks like the result of a bad concatenation or something.

Comment: I took 100+ sql queries, Imported them as 1 giant data frame column. This data are not SQL queries, but the idea is the same.

Comment: `df.loc[df.A.str.contains(r'(?i)(apple|candy|time|\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for multiple conditions here will iterate through the entire column twice, which can get expensive (especially using `pandas`' already slow string operations).  A single regular expression is able to accomplish this task easily:

```
keys = ['apple', 'candy', 'time']
rgx = fr"(?i){'|'.join(keys)}|\d{{2}}/\d{{2}}/\d{{4}}"
```

```
df.loc[df.A.str.contains(rgx)]
```

```
            A           Q           R           S
0       Apple       chair         red     english
3       Apple       chair      purple     english
4  10/01/2016  05/02/2004  05/05/2014  06/20/2018
5  02/20/2017  01/01/2017  07/07/2017  02/04/2004
```

If you're not using Python 3.6+, the same idea can be expressed using `format`:

```
rgx = r"(?i){}|\d{{2}}/\d{{2}}/\d{{4}}".format('|'.join(keys))
```

Comment: what does the "fr" do? Why not use r?

Comment: I've also never seen curly braces used in this context before, the top solution, I've only seen it used for things like "digits{3,6}", how do they work in this case?

Comment: I'm using python f-strings here, where you can execute statements inside curly braces, and the results appear in the string.  However, since regex also use curly braces, I need to wrap them in an additional curly brace to make the regular expression work.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and [`str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html)

```
vals = ['apple', 'candy', 'time']
df.loc[df.A.str.contains('|'.join(vals), case=False) | df.A.str.match(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)')]

    A           Q           R           S
0   Apple       chair       red         english
3   Apple       chair       purple      english
4   10/01/2016  05/02/2004  05/05/2014  06/20/2018
5   02/20/2017  01/01/2017  07/07/2017  02/04/2004
```

Comment: Testing this now

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df[(pd.to_datetime(df.A, errors='coerce').notnull()) | (df.A.str.lower().isin(['apple', 'candy', 'time']))]

            A           Q           R           S
0       Apple       chair         red     english
3       Apple       chair      purple     english
4  10/01/2016  05/02/2004  05/05/2014  06/20/2018
5  02/20/2017  01/01/2017  07/07/2017  02/04/2004
```

As a quick explanation regarding searching for datetimes, `(pd.to_datetime(df.A, errors='coerce')` returns `NaT` if it is not in datetime format, so you can get all the `notnull`, and that will match the datetimes.  Then, use `|` operator, and look for `apple`, `candy` and `time` in addition.